# How can I determine the outliers and remove them as well from my dataset by IQR method?

Tags: python, dataframe, statistics

I want to determine the outliers in my dataframe by the IQR method and then remove them from my dataframe. I have written the following code till now. pubg is the name of my dataframe.

```
Q1 = pubg.quantile(0.25)
Q3 = pubg.quantile(0.75)
IQR = Q3-Q1
IQR
```

But when I write this to find the lower bound outliers I get the error.

```
pubg[pubg<((1.5*IQR)-Q1)].sum()

TypeError: Could not operate array([ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan]) with block values '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'
```

What should I do ?

Comment: Does you dataframe has multiple columns?

Comment: Btw, it should be Q1-1.5*IQR for lower whisker range

Comment: And a third issue, which might be the actual issue. Some of your values are in string format and you're comparing some of them with a float one, so it is supposed to give an error.

Can you share sample data to perform all these operations?

Comment: @AmitAmola These are the columns : 'Id', 'groupId', 'matchId', 'assists', 'boosts', 'damageDealt', 'DBNOs',
       'headshotKills', 'heals', 'killPlace', 'killPoints', 'kills',
       'killStreaks', 'longestKill', 'matchDuration', 'matchType', 'maxPlace',
       'numGroups', 'rankPoints', 'revives', 'rideDistance', 'roadKills',
       'swimDistance', 'teamKills', 'vehicleDestroys', 'walkDistance',
       'weaponsAcquired', 'winPoints', 'winPlacePerc'],  In this, Id, groupId, macthId and matchType are strings. Rest all is float !

Comment: I understood what the problem is. Can you share a sample data or masked data via drive or something? It won't be that difficult to do.